# How to make Jboss Drools 5.5 maintains rules in DB?

Tags: jboss, drools

I am developing custom UI for **Drools 5.5** and I need to know how to let Drools maintains Rules in DB and also how to handle *versioning* like **Guvnour**.

Comment: It's worth noting that in Drools 6, Guvnor makes use of Git for version control of rules, because version control software is better for version control than storing rules in a relational database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK Guvnor uses [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/) in the background to handle versioning etc. Not exactly what you had in mind, but might be a good idea to check it out and see if you can build your custom UI on top of that.